# Saving Target Texture as an image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures

I have got a quad that has got a target texture set through Unity Editor.  I would like to save the output visualization on the quad as an image. Are there any ways to save it as a quad? I have tried through texture2d but its just a black image that is being saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
private void SaveImage(Texture t, string path)
{
    RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(t.width, t.height, 0);
    Graphics.Blit(t, rt);
    Texture2D t2d = new Texture2D(rt.width, rt.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    t2d.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, rt.width, rt.height), 0, 0);
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, t2d.EncodeToPNG());
}
```

Usage

```
SaveImage(yourQuad.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture, "yourSavePath.png");
```